# Any drawback of setting ownership in collection "add" method?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

When you auto-generate doctrine entites with to-many association in Symfony2, you get something like that :

```
/**
 * Add child
 *
 * @param Acme\Entity\Child $child
 * @return Parent
 */
public function addChild(\Acme\Entity\Child $child)
{
    $this->children[] = $child;

    return $this;
}
```

If it's a bi-directional association with owning side on the child (OneToMany are usually like this) any time you add a child you will have to add this line :

```
$parent->addChild($child);
$child->setParent($parent);
```

Usually I end up changing the addChild method, like this :

```
/**
 * Add child
 *
 * @param Acme\Entity\Child $child
 * @return Parent
 */
public function addChild(\Acme\Entity\Child $child)
{
    $this->children[] = $child;
    $child->setParent($this)
    return $this;
}
```

I was just wondering why this is not the default generated method (for bi-directional cases), or if I could do this for all my bi-directional associations without thinking of the usage in my app.

Can you figure out any drawback of this practice ? Any situation where it would cause unexpected/undesired behavior ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you answered it yourself. Not all associations will be bi-directional, which would make this fail for those unidirectional cases if it were the default.

Comment: You think that it's not the default generated method because it depends whether it's uni or bi-directional ? That would make sense (even if there might be way to figure this out). So you say that it should always be added for bi-directional associations, without risk of undesired behavior ?

Comment: You're putting words in my mouth haha. I didn't address the second part because I'm not sure of the best practice there. I hesitate about always adding that line in a bi-directional association.

Comment: I sometimes do what you did but I generally find it a bit clearer (less magic) to call setParent when I create the child object.  Personal preference.

Comment: I don't agree with the "less magic" thing, because the need to call setParent is caused by the fact that the owning side is on the child side, and this is a database concept, not an OOP concept. Plus I don't see a case where you would want the child to be added to the parent's list without the child to have it's parent (especially in a bi-directional OneToMany)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation chapter, [Getting Started: Code First](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#a-first-prototype) (search for "ensure consistency") actually recommends doing this, but from the other way around (doing it on the owning side).

I'm not sure why it's not done automatically by code generation. I don't think the argument that "not every relation is going to be bidirectional" holds, because at code generation time, it is already known which relations are bidirectional, and which are unidirectional.

I think it's just an oversight, the doctrine team always says that the code generation tool should not be relied upon.